# Duplicate file name as folder, insert file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use Powershell to

1. scan folder *D://Mediafolder* for names of media files
2. create a folder for each media file scanned, with same name
3. insert each media file in to matching folder name.

I can find no documentation or thread of this, and I am more fluent in Linux than Windows. I've tried many times to piece this together, but to no avail.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` is the counterpart of `ls`, `New-Item -Type Directory` is the counterpart of `mkdir`. `Copy-Item` / `Move-Item` are the counterparts of `cp` / `mv`. Update your question with attempts to use them and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help :)
This will create a folder for each file with the same name, so if you have a file called xyz.txt, it will create a folder called xyz and move the file to this folder.

```
$path = "D:\MediaFolder"
$items = Get-ChildItem $path 
Foreach ($item in $items)
{
    $folderName = $item.name.Split('.')[0]
    New-Item "$path\$folderName" -ItemType Directory
    Move-Item -Path "$path\$item" -Destination "$path\$foldername"
}
```

Comment: if the folder is having 1 txt file then also it will create a folder for the same. Lets say i have a folder xml.txt, then `$item.name.Trim('.')[0]` will return me X. So it will create a folder named x. Validation has to be there i believe

Comment: Now, what if i have an empty folder structure? we have to remove that also by checking pscontainer. :) i am just pushing you to optimize it . :)

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

File Sorting based on extension should do the job:

```
$folder_path = read-host "Enter the  folder path without space"
$file = gci $folder_path -Recurse | ? {-not $_.psiscontainer} 
$file | group -property extension | % {if(!(test-path(join-path $folder_path -child $_.name.replace('.','')))){new-item -type directory $(join-path $folder_path -child $_.name.replace('.','')).toupper()}}
$file | % {  move-item $_.fullname -destination $(join-path $folder_path -child $_.extension.replace(".",""))}
$a = Get-ChildItem $folder_path -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
$a | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: You can filter all the extensions  in the get-childitem like `gci -include *.mp3`.

Comment: The `-Include` parameter is only used when the `-Recurse` switch is used. The OP did not mention recursion.

Comment: @lit: Thats not necessary. You can use -include independently also. Try this and see the result `Get-ChildItem C:\windows\system32\* -Include *.dll`

Comment: dont know what you meant with that. If I am dont want to go inside all the folders recursively then obviously i will use wildcard only. Anyways

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate over the files in the media_dir and move those with the extensions in media_types to a folder with the same basename. When you are satisfied that the files will be moved to the correct directory, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` statement.

```
PS C:\src\t> type .\ms.ps1
$media_dir = 'C:\src\t\media'
$new_dir = 'C:\src\t\newmedia'
$media_types = @('.mp3', '.mp4', '.jpeg')

Get-ChildItem -Path $media_dir |
    ForEach-Object {
        $base_name = $_.BaseName

        if ($media_types -contains $_.Extension) {
            if (-not (Test-Path $new_dir\$base_name)) {
                New-Item -Path $new_dir\$base_name -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
            }
            Move-Item $_.FullName $new_dir\$base_name -WhatIf
        }
    }
```